# Is there a way to get Firebase data into Edittext based on AutoCompleteTextView selection?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-edittext, sms

I was just wondering is there a way to send a notification sms to a number from Firebase Database ?

All I found after loads and loads of research is Twilio.

Another solution I thought about is to have an invisible edittext that gets populated with the number from firebase based on the person selected in Auto Complete Textview. Or have the number in dots.

So for example if user chooses my name from firebase in the autocompletetextview, my number is loaded in the invisible edittext and then on click of a button I recieve a message.

Anyone know if that would work ? Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try Firebase In-App Messaging, its better and easier.
[DOC](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/)

Comment: What im looking for is more something like: Visitor enters company, they enter check-in, choose the employee they are visiting and onclick that employee receives an sms message / notification :/